# Android ListView won't populate and throws error when extending AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an issue with trying to populate a custom ListView while extending AppCompatActivity. When I extend ListActivity the ListView populates with no issues. But I need to extend other Activities than ListActivity. When I run this code, the error is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.package.twitter/net.package.twitter.main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.ViewGroup.getPaddingLeft()' on a null object reference
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.ViewGroup.getPaddingLeft()' on a null object reference at net.package.twitter.main.onCreate(main.java:16)

**Here is my main class:**

```
package net.package.twitter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Twitter");
    ListView ls = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println(list.toString());
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            list,
            R.layout.custom_row_view,
            new String[]{"user", "time", "text", "screen_name"},
            new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3, R.id.text4}
    );
    ls.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

**Here is the activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="net.package.twitter.main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="383dp"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is the custom_row_view.xml (Custom control of each entry of the ListView):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/> <!--Tweet Account-->
<TextView android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <!--Tweet @ name-->
<!--Tweet Time-->
<TextView android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<!--Tweet Contect-->

</LinearLayout>
```

If anyone could tell me why this is giving me this error that would be great, Thanks!

Comment: try setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);
 before you find your listview ListView ls = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: I got a new error now @JRowan, 

`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.package.twitter/net.package.twitter.main}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.ViewGroup.getPaddingLeft()' on a null object reference`

Comment: can you post the whole error as an edit into your post, and the line of code it is referring to

Comment: Yep Just updated. @JRowan

Comment: try to put super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 right before setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);

Comment: That was exactly it! @JRowan Thanks!

Comment: ill put it as an answer if that's what helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

right before

```
setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);
```